# using paste with a list

Tags: r, paste, strsplit

I'm trying to understand the behavior of `strsplit` and `paste`, which are inverse functions. However, when I `strsplit` a vector, a list is returned, like so:

```
> strsplit(c("on,e","tw,o","thre,e","fou,r"),",")
[[1]]
[1] "on" "e" 

[[2]]
[1] "tw" "o" 

[[3]]
[1] "thre" "e"   

[[4]]
[1] "fou" "r"
```

I tried using `lapply` to `cat` the elements of the list back together, but it doesn't work:

```
> lapply(strsplit(c("on,e","tw,o","thre,e","fou,r"),","),cat)
on etw othre efou r[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
NULL
```

The same formula with `paste` instead of `cat` actually does nothing at all! Why am I getting these results? and how can I get the result I want, which is the original vector back again?

(Obviously, in my actual code I'm trying to do more with the `strsplit` and `cat` than just return the original vector, but I think a solution to this problem will work for mine. Thanks!)

Comment: @RichardScriven any insight on why `cat` gives the strange results above?

Comment: Messing around with the `cat` arguments in `invisible(sapply(strsplit(x, ","), cat, sep = ","))` might help answer that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While yes, `cat` will concatenate and print to the console, it does not actually function in the same way `paste` does. It's result best explained in `help("cat")`

The `collapse` argument in `paste` is effectively the opposite of the `split` argument in `strsplit`. And you can use `sapply` to return the simplified pasted vector.

```
x <- c("on,e","tw,o","thre,e","fou,r")

( y <- sapply(strsplit(x, ","), paste, collapse = ",") )
# [1] "on,e"   "tw,o"   "thre,e" "fou,r" 
( z <- vapply(strsplit(x, ","), paste, character(1L), collapse = ",") )
# [1] "on,e"   "tw,o"   "thre,e" "fou,r"

identical(x, y)
# [1] TRUE
identical(x, z)
# [1] TRUE
```

Note that for cases like this, `vapply` will be more efficient than `sapply`. And adding `fixed = TRUE` in `strsplit` should increase efficiency as well.